# Touch screen not working after using the code" *#*#2663#*#*"

Tags: touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have Samsung Galaxy Mini and I dialled `*#*#2663#*#*` to see the version of the touch screeen.

I pressed the update button, upon which got a message on screen

> updating, do not switch or shut down something like that.

After a few minutes, it displayed version not found, perhaps. After that, touch screen is no longer working.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: i did but it still not working.